# Sharing files across devices

Tags: networking, wireless, server, ftp, vsftpd

So I have a hard drive full of my favorite TV shows, music, and movies. I am running Ubuntu 15.04 desktop. I want to be able to access all my files from all my devices(Android devices) wirelessly over my Wi-Fi connection, say using a file explorer app on my phone. I did a little research and found out I have to setup a vsftpd server but I've had little luck getting it to work. Please help me with this.

What I've already tried:

Installing vsftpd server. I think it was installed successfully but I am not sure. 
Editing the vsftpd.conf file as per many tutorials on the internet.

Thing is I don't know how to proceed from there.
All the tutorials seem to finish it off with, "You've successfully setup an ftp server, enjoy."
What do I do after that is done? I still don't know how to go from there to actually have files opening on my android. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install another service than SSH.

On your mobile device, install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop .

So go to LAN -> FTP and add an SFTP server.
Servername is either the ip or the hostname of your desktop, user and password ist the same like your desktop's.

Comment: Did this help? Please set as solution, or ask me...